# Lazily create database records on GET requests

Tags: web-services, rest, http

First, I understand `GET` requests should be safe and idempotent. However, my current situation is a little bit different from all the examples I have seen, so I'm not sure what to do.

The web app is some kind of metadata database for all online videos (by "all" I actually mean "all YouTube, Vimeo, XXX, ...", i.e., a known range of mainstream online video websites). Users can `POST` to `http://www.example.com/api/video/:id` to add metadata to a certain video, and `GET` from `http://www.example.com/api/video/:id` to get back all the current metadata for the given video.

The problem is how to get the video ID for a URL (say `https://youtu.be/foobarqwe12`). I think the users can query the server somehow, perhaps with a `GET` at `http://www.example.com/api/find_video?url=xxx`. The idea is that as long as the URL is valid, the query should always return the information of the video (including its ID); this seems to require that the server creates the record for a video if it doesn't exist yet.

My opinion is that although this seems to violate the safety and idempotence requirements for `GET` requests, it can also be seen as implementation detail (ideally there is a record for every video for every URL at the beginning of time, and lazily creating records on `GET`s is just a kind of optimization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonsense, it doesn't violate anything.

If "every valid resource name" has a "valid representation", how that representation is manifested is an internal detail that's outside scope.

Your GET is idempotent. Just because you create a new row in a DB on first access doesn't make it not so.

When you GET /missingurl, you get a representation -- not a 404, but a 200 and some kind of result. This representation could also just be a templated boilerplate that all entities get (only with the URL linked filled in).

Whether you simply print some templated boilerplate, or create a row in the DB, the representation to the client is the same. They make the request, they get the representation -- all the time, all the same. That's idempotent. The fact "something happens" on the backend in an implementation detail hidden from the client.